# DIV should be refreshed only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result == 1) {
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).load('/echo/json/', function () {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        }, 1025544);

    }
}
```

Friends on success function I have to refresh the myDiv DIV only once but as the above code the DIV is keep on fade out and fade in continuously instead it should work only once

Comment: Well you use *interval* which repeats....

Answer (score 5):

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval) repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It will continue to do so until `clearInterval` is called.
It is easiest just to use  [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), which just delays the function being called for the specified time:

```
var auto_refresh = setTimeout(function() {
  $('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).load('/echo/json/', function() {
      $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  });
}, 1025544);
```

Answer (score 0):

using a variable name `auto_refresh` kind of indicates you want it to repeat. also -> 1025544ms = 17mins. so it will refresh every 17 mins.

if you want it to not show, wait 17mins then show, use **@Jacod Grays** Answer.

if you just want it to show, remove the `setInterval` like so :-

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result == 1) {
       $('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow', function () {
           $(this).load('/echo/json/', function () {
              $(this).fadeIn('slow');
           });
       });
    }
}
```